# QueryObject Include Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, include, objectquery

I have three tables: Scenarios, Components and Blocks. Blocks has a foreign key to ComponentId and Components has a foreign key to Scenarios.

Blocks also has a foreign key (TreeStructureId) to another table TreeStructures.

Now, why does this work:

```
ObjectQuery<Blocks> blocks = edumatic3Entities.Blocks.Include("TreeStructures").Include("Components.Scenarios");
```

It loads the TreeStructures, Components and Scenarios.

This however doesn't work:

```
ObjectQuery<Blocks> blocks = edumatic3Entities.Blocks.Include("Components.Scenarios").Include("TreeStructures");
```

This loads the Components and Scenarios but doesn't load the TreeStructures...

Seems very strange to me... Why is this?

thx, Lieven Cardoen

Comment: have you tried to reproduce the problem by loading a clean edmx with a northwind db?

Comment: Seems like I fixed the problem not knowing why. Probably did something stupid. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly set the relations between the entities in your **logical model**? Is it set up in a way that allows navigation from Scenarios s to TreeStructures? Having a foreign key is not enough afaik.

Comment: Yes, it is set, otherwise I guess the first example of code wouldn't work either. That's the strange thing you see. It's like the order of the Include matters...